# Jquery Tabs - Using External URL link

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs, hyperlink

I'm using the Jquery UI Tabs, and have a question.

```
<div id="ui-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1"><span>My First Tab</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2"><span>My Second Tab</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.someothersite.com/"><span>My Third Tab</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is it possible to get that **third tab** to actually go to the off-site URL when clicked?  I tried this, but the link was ignored, so I'm not sure if I've done something wrong, or if it's just not possible as written.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty but this works

```
    <li><a href="#tabs-3"><a href="http://espn.com">ESPN</a></a></li>
```

Sample is here http://codepen.io/martypowell/pen/leGaz

Comment: this works but it causes my the name to be forced off to the RIGHT
[http://puu.sh/69tua.png](http://puu.sh/69tua.png) Why is that?

Comment: this is a really bad way to code i found out later, putting 1 a href within another, i already solved my issue thanks tho.