# Jquery specific tab opens url instead of tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Like the title says, I want use my last Tab as a URL link to another webpage within my website without having to specify the entire url, I know this probably requires some sort of javascript. Below are the things I've tried.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
       <li> <a href="#tabs-1"> Tab 1</ a> </ li>
       <li> <a href="#tabs-2"> Tab 2 </ a> </ li>
       <li> <a href="#tabs-3"> Link </ a> </ li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
       <p> Tab 1 content </ p>
    </ div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
       <p> Tab 2 content </ p>
    </ div>
    <div id="tabs-3"></ div> //shouldn't be needed etc
</ div>.
```

I've tried this:

```
<li><a href="#tabs-3"><a href="http://randomurl.com">Home</a></a></li>
```

[Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980268/jquery-tabs-using-external-url-link)

But this happens: The image is off center, i'm assuming its because of the double a href.

[image]

does anyone have any other suggestions? I've searched for a solution but nothing really presented itself. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested `<a>` tags is not valid HTML, so I would advise against using the workaround in the SO question you mentioned.

You can add an onclick listener for the external links, like so:

The HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#tabs-1"> Tab 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tabs-2"> Tab 2 </a></li>
       <li><a href="http://example.com" class="external"> Link </a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
       <p> Tab 1 content </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
       <p> Tab 2 content </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $('.external').click(function(){
        window.location.href=$(this).attr('href'); //opens in same tab/window

        //window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank'); //opens in new tab  
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cRW5y/

Comment: this is my code and opens back into the same tab: `<li><a href='../index.php' class='external'><img src='home_25.png' style='width:21px;' /></a></li>`

Comment: You haven't said if you want it to open the link in a new tab, or in the existing. This code is for opening in the existing tab/window.   Do you want it in a new tab?

Comment: ? I want use my last Tab as a URL link to another webpage, sorry if this wasn't clear, but I want it to act as a normal link, going to another url, `'_self'`

Comment: You need an absolute URL in the `href` attribute (starting with `http://` or `https://`), so the browser will recognize it as external.

Comment: ok, I've tested your code using http:// and it doesn't even work. does this JavaScript code need to be written below the tabs div or can it be in the header, lastly, I HAS to be href='../index.php' so if you need to change the answer to fit this format that would be awesome

Comment: I've edited my answer, check it. Place the javascript code after the tabs div (if it's wrapped in `$(document).ready()`, it can be placed in the `head`, after the jquery scripts ). As for the `href`, you're saying that you want the link to point to an external site, but you also say you need it to be `href="../index.php"`, which is not an external link, it's just relative. The code will work with any URL you provide (absolute or relative, external or not).

Answer (score 0):

I think small jQuery code will help:

```
$(function(){
  $('#tabs-3').click(function(){
    window.open("http://randomurl.com", '_blank');
  });
})
```

Comment: does this code have to written before or after the div? because I have written in my header, and it doesn't do anything

Comment: Better if you can put the Js on bottom

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you can accomplish opening the last link in a new tab without javascript. In html, the last link would look like this ...

```
<li><a href="http://example.com" class="external" target="_blank"> Link </a></li>
```

You just need to add target="_blank"

Comment: This won't work, according to the fact that jQuery prevents the default action of the link, and also a jsFiddle test.

Comment: I don't want to open into a blank page regardless